# PHP stream_select alwasy returns with server socket

Tags: php, sockets, stream

When using `stream_select()` on an array which contains the server socket created with `stream_socket_server()` and also the client sockets it always returns instantly with the server socket selected.

My understanding of `stream_select()` is that it should only return when the server socket state has changed (or timeout is reached). This should only happen if a new client is trying to connect or one client has sent data.

I have written the following code:

```
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://localhost:8888");
$connections['master'] = $socket;

while(true) {
    $w = $e = null;
    $r = $connections;
    if (stream_select($r, $w, $e, 1) !== false) {
        foreach ($r as $socket) {
            if ($socket === $connections['master']) {
                $conn = stream_socket_accept($socket);
                $connections[] = $conn;
            } else {
                // Handle communication with client...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, I get a non-stop running loop where `$r` everytime contains the server socket, but `stream_socket_accept()` throws an error because there is no client trying to connect.

What am I doing wrong? Or is my understanding about `stream_select()` wrong?

Comment: In the code you posted you use `socket_select` not `stream_select`

Comment: Thank you, @t.m.adam, but it's still the same behaviour.